# Why didn’t Picard just stun his future self?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard

In TNG "Time Squared", Picard meets himself from the not-so-distant future. Trying to prevent the future Picard from making the same mistake again (which led to the destruction of Enterprise in an alternative timeline), he takes out a phaser and kills him as he was entering the shuttle.

The question is: couldn't he just stun him?

Comment: It's a well known fact of parallel worlds that by killing your parallel self, you consume their power.  There can be only one!

Comment: NICE. "I am JEAN-LUC!  I am NOOOObody's bitch!"

Comment: It always struck me that the alt-Picard was unlike the real Picard. His attitude and demeanour were dramatically different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's clear from the events that he intentionally kills his future self, <s>or even that he actually does - at least not with the phaser.</s> The solution to their problem effectively erases the second Picard from existence, so he was doomed from the start.

- The future Picard is a mess. He is barely recovered from being 'out of sync' with the current time frame; previously he was delirious beyond ability to even communicate at all. Sometimes, injured or unstable life-forms/starships which would normally be disabled by a low-intensity phaser blast end up dying without any intent to kill on behalf of the aggressor. The phaser blast may have simply been more than his scrambled neural pathways could handle.
- In support of the previous point; he pulls the phaser directly from storage and **fires without changing the settings**. Typically phasers have to be *set to kill*; they don't just come on with 'kill' as the default setting. Indeed a phaser with the raw energy to disrupt rock faces would be a horribly dangerous weapon if it didn't require being manually set to such a setting before being fired. It's a bit like a television that doesn't turn itself down after being powered off -- annoying as hell, only substitute "incredibly deadly" for "annoying". If indeed it was intended to remember its previous setting, then surely some Ensign somewhere is about to get a negative mark on their quarterly review for stowing a weapon on a kill setting!
- <s>I'm *fairly* certain that no one has a chance to monitor his vitals or affirm his status before he phases out during the resolution of the episode.</s> **I'm wrong on this, he does appear quite dead after being monitored by Dr. Pulaski!** However -- even if Picard had merely intended to stun him, he'd have ceased to exist anyway, which is arguably on a par with killing, depending on your view of temporal mechanics as they apply to such causality violations. (how can he travel back in time if he successfully escapes the anomaly?)

Really, there was never going to be a chance to keep the second Picard within the context of this episode. He was instantiated after the first failed attempt to escape the anomaly, which then caused the first attempt to be altered by giving them vital information about how *not* to proceed, so the alt-first attempt having succeeded, time-travelin' Picard can never have been created in the first place. It's a bit wibbly.

Comment: Doesn't O'Brien report to the bridge on the alternate Picard being dead?

Comment: He reports in that he's ceased to exist, so kind of -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WY7_Dbgx9Xs

Comment: Unrelated, O'Brien is the only person not holding on for dear life while the ship is shaking to bits and the shuttlebay door is still open. He just stands there. Like a boss.

Comment: "However -- even if Picard had merely intended to stun him, he'd have ceased to exist anyway, which is arguably on a par with killing" -- But did Picard actually know that's what would have happened? Unless this type of situation has cropped up before, he couldn't have been sure that the other Picard wouldn't just be able to continue on with his own life after recovering from being stunned (as Riker's double would in a later ep). Maybe Picard just didn't really see him as a separate individual since so little time had passed since their histories diverged, so he wouldn't consider it murder.

Comment: I don't think there's a basis for comparison between Picard2 in this episode and Riker2 in Second Chances, but moving on - Starfleet personnel have been versed in temporal mechanics and temporal ethics to the best understanding of the times, though they leave it to the Spocks and Datas to do the intellectual heavy lifting. If Spock is able to compute warp slingshots to get to and from the 20th century, others may have borrowed against this knowledge to conduct causality experiments. That's conjecture, of course! In *this* situation, I submit he can hazard an 'educated guess' at least.

Comment: "In support of the previous point; he pulls the phaser directly from storage and fires without changing the settings. Typically phasers have to be set to kill; they don't just come on with 'kill' as the default setting." But when Picard2 was shot, sparks flew from his chest where he was hit, does that ever happen with phasers on stun? And phasers are shown being set to stun just like they are shown being set to kill, I don't think we can assume anything about the default setting of a phaser in the shuttlecraft bay (aside from the issue that the writers may just not have thought about it).

Comment: Less than a year prior, two phasers set to kill strip away the layers of an alien-infested human's skin down to the bone before causing them to pop (...don't cross the streams, I guess). By contrast, later kill settings (on all manner of hand weapon) just *vaporize* the target. **IOW** - I think the SFX weren't quite codified yet. *(Also - I wonder how often they are setting to 'stun' or 'MAXIMUM stun' when they are tweaking the phasers as you've noted. In early episodes they are seen setting phasers before transport - but **typically** they just draw, then fire, then tweak on a whiff.)*

Comment: And there's always the old "phaser on stun at close range" bit, though that's hardly close range - but again, I'll point to Picard2's temporal/mental/neural degradation. He was still under a lot of duress and not acting entirely familiar while he was leaving - highly atypical. And even by modern safety standards weapons aren't stored in a 'fireable' state - since we don't really see anyone 'loading' a hand phaser, isn't it fair to assume they at least turn it down to a nonlethal setting when they're stowed? Phasers can cause far more damage than a Desert Eagle, I'd wager safety is crucial

Comment: _"Typically phasers have to be set to kill; they don't just come on with 'kill' as the default setting"_ -- on the contrary, I am pretty sure that I remember someone saying at some point during TNG that standard procedure requires phasers being set to minimum output prior to storage.

Comment: If that's so then it means someone forgot to power the phaser down, so...

Comment: It's interesting that no one knows which setting did Picard actually use. O'Brien and Pulaski only see the dead future Picard, so.. who knows what captain did?

Comment: Having just watched the episode, I think your first bullet point is the real reason behind this.  I think the other Picard is so weak and out of sync that the phaser does more harm than it normally would.  I think it's clear that he does die(just from the way Pulaski shakes her head), but as you said his existence was doomed from the start, so in the end, it doesn't matter.